# How to convert a mxn matrix into a vector with same rows?

Tags: matrix, vector, julia, vectorization

I'm trying to convert a Matrix into SVector in Julia. Following is a sample of how to create a matrix

```
p=randn(Point3,100)
p_mat=collect(reshape(reduce(vcat,p),3,length(p))')
```

[image]
Here is the matrix.
[image]

I've one method but its not very optimal.

```
[SVector{size(p_mat,2), Real}(p_mat[i,:]) for i in 1:size(p_mat,1)]
```

I'm trying to avoid the for loop and convert matrix into SVector.
Is there another possible way?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. What is `Point3`? Do you mean 'collect matrix into _vector of SVectors_'? And what is the purpose of `p` in this question? Is it actually `p` you want to convert? If not, I suggest removing `p` from the question, and directly creating the matrix as input, otherwise people will be distracted with trying to directly go from `p` to the output, bypassing `p_exp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume `Point3` is just another name for `SVector{3, Float64}`. Then, you can create a Vector from the matrix rows by `Point3.(eachrow(p_mat))` as follows:

```
using StaticArrays
const Point3 = SVector{3, Float64}

p = randn(Point3, 100)
100-element Vector{SVector{3, Float64}}:
 [-0.643411054127986, -1.3146948793707078, 0.8560043466425089]
 [-1.2014944236615475, -0.16332265198198045, 0.7899287791641353]
 [-0.4468974734632806, -2.115137061106782, 1.2797367438232168]
 ...

p_mat = [v[i] for v in p, i in 1:3]
100×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 -0.643411   -1.31469     0.856004
 -1.20149    -0.163323    0.789929
 -0.446897   -2.11514     1.27974
 ...

p_vec = Point3.(eachrow(p_mat)) # the same as p
100-element Vector{SVector{3, Float64}}:
 [-0.643411054127986, -1.3146948793707078, 0.8560043466425089]
 [-1.2014944236615475, -0.16332265198198045, 0.7899287791641353]
 [-0.4468974734632806, -2.115137061106782, 1.2797367438232168]
 ...
```